# file_get_contents to https server suddenly started failing

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt, caddy

I have a number of sites running on [caddy](https://caddyserver.com).  I call between them on the same machine from php apps

```
file_get_contents('https://myapi.example.com/my/api/call');
```

up until today it was all working lovely then I started getting

> SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

All my certs are from LetsEncrypt.org which have been fetched by Caddy, and since they were working up until very recently I am wondering what has changed.

I have tried setting

```
 verify_peer = false
```

in various contexts with no success and also I know this kindof breaks SSL which is not a good long term solution.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally I don't know what caused this error, but revoking my cert and getting a new one solved the problem.

Simply call Caddy with

```
caddy -revoke myapi.example.com
```

then restart caddy and the problem was solved.